# Define variable in header.php and use it in home.tpl in opencart

Tags: global-variables, opencart

I searched for my answer here, but didnt found anything...
Im using opencart 2.1.0.1 and i need to declare a variable in header.php controller an use it in home.tpl
after this in header.php:

```
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
public function index() {
```

im adding this:

```
if($this->request->get['route'] == 'common/home'){  
        $data['pagetype']= 'home';
    }
```

What i want to use in home.tpl is the variable `$pagetype` which is keeping the string `'home'`
Im using vqmod xml file to import everything. 
Thanks all of you for helping me !
I need this because i want to properly implement the google remarketing dynx tags.

Edit: 
I tryed also to declare it in home.php - but with no result!

Comment: Anybody can help me with this global variable?

Comment: Have you checked the vqcache file that your code is actually added?

Comment: I checked it...no, its not added in header.php

Comment: Edit the question, add the vqmod xml file you used, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your function just add:

```
return $this->load->view('path to your file', $data);
```

U can see examples in other core controllers in Opencart.